# Spring boot Thymeleaf displaying image from db;

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am going crazy because I am spending a whole day and I still cannot solve this problem. In my opinion, It is the right path and I also used absolute path for image like file:// something, but it did not work either. What I want is to display images in array list object.
In the first picture, image does not show even though it is the right path in console, and second picture is th:src="${list.storedFilePath}" which is I used for image tag. I am new to thymeleaf and I searched on google and looked up all the resources, but still could not solve.( p.s I tried th:src="'/' + ${list.storedFilePath}" but it did not work either.)

This is my view page

```
 <div class="row cat-pd" onclick="location.href='productDetail.do'">
                     <div class="col-md-6" style="width:280px;" th:each="list:${list}">
                        <div class="small-box-c">
                           <div class="small-img-b">
                              <img th:src="'http://localhost:8090/'+${list.storedFilePath}" class="img-responsive"  alt="Image"/>
                           </div>
                           <div class="dit-t clearfix">
                              <div class="left-ti">
                                 <h4 th:text="${list.pName}"></h4>
                                 <p>By <span>Beko</span> under <span>Lights</span></p>
                              </div>
                              <a th:text="${list.price}+'원(하루)'"> <br>
                                     </a>
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
```

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer{

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        commonsMultipartResolver.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(5 * 1024 * 1024);
        return commonsMultipartResolver;
    }
```

```
@Component
public class FileUtils {
    
    public List<FileDto> parseFileInfo(int pNo, MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartHttpServletRequest) throws Exception{
        
        if(ObjectUtils.isEmpty(multipartHttpServletRequest)) {
            return null;
        }
        List<FileDto> fileList = new ArrayList<>();
        
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"); 
        ZonedDateTime current = ZonedDateTime.now();
        String path = "images/"+current.format(format);
        File file1 = new File(path);
        if(file1.exists() == false){
            file1.mkdirs();
        }
        
        Iterator<String> iterator = multipartHttpServletRequest.getFileNames();
        
        String newFileName, originalFileExtension, contentType;
        
        while(iterator.hasNext()){
            List<MultipartFile> list = multipartHttpServletRequest.getFiles(iterator.next());
            for (MultipartFile multipartFile : list){
                if(multipartFile.isEmpty() == false){
                    contentType = multipartFile.getContentType();
                    if(ObjectUtils.isEmpty(contentType)){
                        break;
                    }
                    else{
                        if(contentType.contains("image/jpeg")) {
                            originalFileExtension = ".jpg";
                        }
                        else if(contentType.contains("image/png")) {
                            originalFileExtension = ".png";
                        }
                        else if(contentType.contains("image/gif")) {
                            originalFileExtension = ".gif";
                        }
                        else{
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    
                    newFileName = Long.toString(System.nanoTime()) + originalFileExtension;
                    FileDto file = new FileDto();
                    file.setpNo(pNo);
                    file.setFileSize(multipartFile.getSize());
                    file.setOrigin(multipartFile.getOriginalFilename());
                    file.setStoredFilePath(path + "/" + newFileName);
                    fileList.add(file);
                    
                    file1 = new File(path + "/" + newFileName);
                    multipartFile.transferTo(file1);
                }
            }
        }
        return fileList;
    
    }
}
```

controller

```
@RequestMapping("/viewProductList.pr")
public ModelAndView selectProductList(@RequestParam int cNo) throws Exception{
    
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("/productCategory");
    
    
    List<ProductDto> list = pService.selectProductList(cNo);
    mv.addObject("list", list);
    
    return mv;
}
```

[image: image does not display even though there is a right path in console.][image: I used th:src="${list.storedFilePath}".in brower, it shows the right path, but still does not work.]

Comment: Hi there, could you copy your code into your question, rather than using screenshots of the code.

Comment: When you view the source and see: `<img src="images/20200713/334248932248796.png" />` (as in your picture), that means the Thymeleaf part is working.   You need to figure out why your picture really isn't at `http://localhost:8090/images/20200713/334248932248796.png` (and what the url really should it be).

Comment: Hello, I am sorry not uploading the code, I just copied my code into question.

Comment: @Metroids I tried.. so I tried to check the path of the properties of my image folder and copied and pasted into the source, but it did not work either.

Comment: @john I think I found your problem. Copy the **images** folder and paste that folder into "src->main->resources->static"

Comment: @Avijit what the.... I have done it before, but it did not work. now it works... thank you..!!

Comment: @john  Can I post it as an answer, so that if other face this issue they will get help from your answer?